# Salesforce Lightning: How can i get session Id of current user in Salesforce lightning component?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have a requirement to call REST API from Salesforce lightning component, for that i need to have session id of that user while requesting a REST service. But, in current version (Summer 18) of Salesforce the session id i'm getting from UserInfo is always Invalid, that means salesforce doesn't give session id in Summer 18 release. Is there any alternative to get session Id in Summer18?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. It looks that Session Id retrieved in Lightning context does not have privileges to authorize REST requests...

I used workaround to get Session Id in Lightning context via Visualforce context.

Create following Visualforce page with `SessionId` name:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" lightningStylesheets="false">
    <span style="display: none">
        SESSION_ID_START{!$API.Session_ID}SESSION_ID_END
    </span>
</apex:page>
```

Create `getSessionIdFromVFPage()` utility method to get content of `SessionId` page and retrieve value of Session Id:

```
public class Util {
    public static String getSessionIdFromVFPage() {
        if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
            return 'SESSION_ID';
        } else {
            String SESSION_ID_START = 'SESSION_ID_START';
            String SESSION_ID_END = 'SESSION_ID_END';
            String pageContent = Page.SessionId.getContent().toString();
            Integer startIndex = pageContent.indexOf(SESSION_ID_START) + SESSION_ID_START.length();
            Integer endIndex = pageContent.indexOf(SESSION_ID_END);
            return pageContent.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Value of Session Id returend by `Util.getSessionIdFromVFPage()` method and used in Lightning context works for my requests (i.e. in @AuraEnabled methods).